# c# edit method overwrite all or only save changes fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my EDIT actions in my MVC app I currently overwrite all the model fields for each edit. e.g. if I edit just the address of a user record, the save will overwrite the other fields (like surname and firstname with the already saved values.
This doesnt seem like best practice (saving a field where there are no changes).
Is this right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry about it. Entity Framework tracks changes internally, so it knows what it needs to update and what it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, i have one more related query - could you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643480/does-my-post-edit-action-overwrite-all-fields-in-ef